# Why use a Mutex to lock on?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, mutex

Why would someone use a new mutex just for locking?

```
public class Job
{
    private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

    public void Execute(Context context)
    {
        lock (mutex)
        {
            // some work here
        }

        // some more work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this really is the only use of said `Mutex`, then it does indeed not make sense. A normal `object` would have been enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would someone use a new mutex just for locking?

Probably because someone in a tutorial said "Mutex", and they literally thought of the `Mutex` object. There is no benefit or any special effects to using it as a `lock`. Any reference type has an Object Header Word making it eligible for use as a `lock` object.

Side note - locking using a `static` object will cause any instance of your `Job` class to be blocked while another instance is holding that lock.